# Ubuntu installation stuck at fb0: switching to interldrmfb from EFI VGA

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, macbook

I'm trying to install ubuntu from a bootable USB. Inside gnu grub I choose the option "Ubuntu" and, after a while, it got stuck at `fb0: switching to interldrmfb from EFI VGA.`

What can I do?

My device is a Macbook air 2019 with big sur. I have refind installed, secure boot disabled, booting from external media enabled.

I don't know much about Linux in general, please be as detailed as possible. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to set kernel parameter like this(video=):

Grub black screen (efi mode) press 'e' key and find line: linux "quiet splash video=simplefb:off"
and press f10 to try to boot

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to use the `video=off` kernel parameter

Do not forget to perform `update-grub` at the end.